# Routed events and Dependency propetries

Tags: wpf

I have a user control with a dependency property. When that property is changed, I want to cascade a RoutedEvent up to the main application and execute some function. Here is my user control code:

```
    public TCardBase SelectedTCard
    {
        get { return (TCardBase)GetValue(SelectedTCardProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedTCardProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedTCard.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTCardProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTCard", typeof(TCardBase), typeof(TCardView), new PropertyMetadata(SelectedTCardPropertyChanged));


    private static void SelectedTCardPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //SEND EVENT HERE TO MAIN APPLICATION
    }
```

What is the best way to send this event to the main application? Thanks.

Comment: What type of event are you trying to raise? "Selected Card" seems like something you should rather handle at the ViewModel level, not the UI. BTW, what `exactly` do you mean by `main application`? Routed events are not supposed to be handled by "the application", but rather by a UI element or something.

Comment: So the user control is bound to a view model that displays a list of items. The "main application" contains this user control, so I just wanted the user control to be able to tell the main app. to run some function when the user control property "SelectedTCard" changed.

Comment: You should be using a `Selector` based UI element (such as a `ListBox`) if you need selection capabilities, and binding the `SelectedItem` property to some relevant property in the ViewModel, and reacting to that change in the ViewModel level. Why do you want to overcomplicate everything using `RoutedEvent`s and the like?

Comment: The control I am using(The Telerik RadTileView) isn't a selector based control. So "selection" occurs at a different level(when the user clicks a button inside a metro tile). So when the user clicks this button, I need to have a custom property SelectedTCard. Then I need to alert the main window that the property changed.

Comment: your approach is backwards. Give your `Button`s a common `Command` in the ViewModel and pass some relevant data item as the `CommandParameter`. Again, you're just setting yourself for unneeded complications by not doing this the MVVM way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of nice examples online how to create custom routed events.

Take a look at this code:

```
// This event uses the bubbling routing strategy 
public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(TCardView));

// Provide CLR accessors for the event 
public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
{
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); } 
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
}

// This method raises the Tap event 
void RaiseTapEvent()
{
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(TCardView.TapEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}

public TCardBase SelectedTCard
{
    get { return (TCardBase)GetValue(SelectedTCardProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedTCardProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedTCard.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTCardProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTCard", typeof(TCardBase), typeof(TCardView), new PropertyMetadata(SelectedTCardPropertyChanged));


private static void SelectedTCardPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TCardView)o).RaiseTapEvent();
}
```

Try it out. :)

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed! So many things came together.